# How to change encoding from Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators to UTF-8?

Tags: character-encoding, text

I have a txt file  :

```
$ file -i x.txt
x.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
$ file x.txt 
x.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

And there are some characters that are incorrectly encoded :

```
trwa³y, sta³y, usuwaæ
```

How can I change this file's encoding to UTF-8 ? I have tried the following way so far :

```
$ iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 x.txt
                puiconv: illegal input sequence at position 4
```

Maybe I should somehow use `extended ASCII` ( `high ASCII` ) but cannot find it in `iconv`'s encoding list.

Comment: can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: There is a handy list of 8-bit ISO encodings, all shown side-by-side, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859).  Do any of them look close to what you observe in your file?  For example, if you think "sta³y" should be "stacy", then find which encoding has a "c" for whatever the strange hex code is in that word.

Comment: Probably 90% of the time, "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text" will be a file encoded in [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codepage. _"It is probably the most-used 8-bit character encoding in the world."_ (Wikipedia). Try it first: `iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 file`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`file` tells you “Non-ISO extended-ASCII text” because it detects that this is:

- most likely a “text” file from the lack of control characters (byte values 0–31) other than line breaks;
- “extended-ASCII” because there are characters outside the ASCII range (byte values ≥128);
- “non-ISO” because there are characters in the 128–159 range ([ISO 8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859) reserves this range for control characters).

You have to figure out which encoding this file seems to be in. You can try [Enca](http://freecode.com/projects/enca)'s automatic recognition. You might need to nudge it in the right direction by telling it in what language the text is.

```
enca x.txt
enca -L polish x.txt
```

To convert the file, pass the `-x` option: `enca -L polish x.txt -x utf8 >x.utf8.txt`

If you can't or don't want to use Enca, you can guess the encoding manually. A bit of looking around told me that this is Polish text and the words are trwały, stały, usuważ, so we're looking for a translation where `³` → `ł` and `æ` → `ż`. This looks like [latin-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) or [latin-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) or more likely (given “non-ISO” [CP1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP1250) which you're viewing as [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). To convert the file to UTF-8, you can use [recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html) or [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv).

```
recode CP1250..utf8 <x.txt >x.utf8.txt
iconv -f CP1250 -t UTF-8 <x.txt >x.utf8.txt
```

Comment: I don't get part with `< x.txt > x.utf8.txt` Why do we use `<` and then `>`? How does it work?

Comment: @FilipBartuzi `<` and `>` perform [input and output redirection respectively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).

Comment: Weird that `enca` doesn't support English. Just some eastern and central European languages, Russian and Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Open the text file with gedit and in the "save as.." dialog you will see the current encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find out what exact encoding is x.txt?
You'll get a list of supported encodings with

> iconv --list

Sometimes it happens to me that I get a mismatch between latin1 and utf8. Then it often helps to convert it from and back to utf8 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an automated [conversion script](https://gist.github.com/Barlog951/69aceea68c38230c57d6658884e2349c) using the [enca](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) library,
I use it on my NAS to convert subtitles to UTF-8 but it could be utilized for any automated conversion

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LANGUAGE="czech"
TO="utf8"
CONVERT="enca -L $LANGUAGE -x $TO"

# Find and convert
find ./ -type f -name "*.srt" | while read -r fn; do
  IS_TARGET=$(enca "${fn}" | grep -E -ow -m 1 'UTF-8|Unrecognized|KOI8-CS2|7bit ASCII|UCS-2|Macintosh Central European')

    if [ "$IS_TARGET" != "UTF-8" ] &&
      [ "$IS_TARGET" != "UCS-2" ] &&
      [ "$IS_TARGET" != "Macintosh Central European" ] &&
      [ "$IS_TARGET" != "Unrecognized" ] &&
      [ "$IS_TARGET" != "7bit ASCII" ] &&
      [ "$IS_TARGET" != "KOI8-CS2" ]; then

      echo "${fn} ---- Will be converted!"
      # optional backup of original srt
      # cp "${fn}" "${fn}.bak"
      $CONVERT "${fn}"
    fi  
done
```