# Convert text file to non-iso extended ascii file

Tags: linux, character-encoding, od

I have a file which is Non-ISO Extended ASCII type. I can't see its content just by opening it normally via cat or vim.
However, I'm able to see its content in readable form with this command...

```
od -w128 file.txt
```

Does anyone know how this file was created in the first place ?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/732589/513541 (one origin was "German WindowsXP installation") and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108271/117549

Comment: Another possible source: [S3 CSV's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39806427/4957508), or the [FCC](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/66057)

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a number of codepages from the DOS era.  Perhaps the most popular was CP 850, for Western European languages.  Quite some Microsoft software still produces such files; also, Unicode was initially rejected in the Far East, so we still find files in particular codings, generally known as CJK.  You can try `enca` to find how your file is coded.

But no, it is not possible to know how it was created in the first place.

VIM itself *can* read such files, as it can convert from a range of encodings when reading files for editing.  This is done with the `++enc=encoding` option to the `:edit` command.  So, for example, if you determine that the non-ISO 8-bit extended-ASCII encoding in question *really is* code page 850, this can be read into VIM with:

```
:edit ++enc=cp850 file.txt
```

See `:help encoding-names`.

Comment: You could make this answer even better by pointing out that one _can_ read (say) code page 850 text into VIM and how one achieves that.

Comment: Is there a way, I can create such a file and read it with od -w128?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @JdeBP, but `vim` is not quite my cup of tea.  In GNU Emacs I know it is trivial to change the encoding interpretation when opening or refreshing a file.

@yogiboy, i could not understand your comment.  I understand the file is already created; what exactly do you need?

Comment: @lfd6 mate, I meant, say I have a file abc.txt with abc in it(normal text utf8 kind). How do I create another file with abc in it but now it is a noniso extended ascii file? And if I now want to see its content, I must do something like "od -w128 newfile.txt".

Comment: @yogiboy, why would you want to create a file in an obsolete encoding?  There are quite some utilities to convert or create file in arbitrary encodings; GNU Emacs for instance has extensive capabilities, described in its Info manual, 22.5.  An interesting utility to convert is `iconv`.  Only be sure to not ‘nonISO extended ASCII’ is but a generic description of any non-Unicode codepage.