# Fix character encoding chaos

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding

I‘m building a script to extract some data from a website with broken character encoding:

- The html header claims it‘s iso-8859-1, but it‘s not
- `wget`ting the file shows me it‘s actually utf-8, but with wrong characters
- Reverse engineering shows me that someone managed to use the windows codepage 1252 as unicode code!

So for example the backtick is 0x91 in codepage 1252 and is U+0091 in this page. Weird. Amazingly, web browsers seem to be able to repair this automagically.

My question: Which tool can help me clean this mess? (Not by hand! This is a dynamic website with hundreds of pages and I saw at least six different false encodings.)

Comment: Using a different User-Agent could help. Please try.

Comment: Is there a test-page you can point us at? Or are you just looking for helpful suggestions?

Comment: @jubilatious1 Yes, I asked for a tool and got the right hint. I new `iconv`, but I wouldn't have tested it on irregular encoded input. But it worked for some reason.

Comment: More precisely, backtick aka grave accent is an ASCII character, at 0x60 in ASCII like in windows-1252 or any other superset of ASCII. The character at 0x91 in windows-1252 is the left single quotation mark (`‘` U+2018). U+0091 encoded as 0xc2 0x91 in UTF-8 would be a *private use* control character. If you wanted to get from 0xc2 0x91 to a UTF-8 encoded U+2018, you'd need `iconv -f utf8 -t l1 | iconv -f cp1252 -t utf8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean with "Not by hand", `iconv` could be useful for your task.

> iconv - convert text from one character encoding to another
>
> OPTIONS
>
> ```
>    -f from-encoding, --from-code=from-encoding
>           Use from-encoding for input characters.
>
>    -t to-encoding, --to-code=to-encoding
>           Use to-encoding for output characters.
> ```

In my experience, iconv works even if you have to deal with wrong encodings. For example, you can tell iconv that the input data is utf-8 encoded, even though it's iso-8859, so that iconv acts as if the input would be utf-8. This way you can repair incorrectly encoded data.

Since iconv can work as a filter, you can chain it with something like `curl`. Chaining with `wget` should work as well, when you use `--output-document -`.

From what i know, iconv isn't able to detect/guess the correct input encoding. But depending on how messed your input data is, this might be "impossible" anyway, if the website has (too) many different types of wrong/mix encoding. If the whole website is messed up the same way, you should be able to fix it.

Comment: Piping the input through `iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF8` did indeed do the trick, although the input was no real CP1252. I don't understand it, but it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you want your `locale` in UTF-8.

### To detect

- [`chardetect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) (from python3-chardet package; AKA chardet)
- [`uchardet`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet/), encoding detector library (now on freedesktop)
- [`enca`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enca), focused on eastern and central European languages
- ```bash
  file --brief --mime-encoding FILE | awk '{print $2}' FS=':[ :]+'
  ```

Usual suspects are: CP850, CP437, latin1 (AKA ISO-8859-1), CP1252 (AKA windows-1252).

In my experience, pretty often these tools doesn't do the job. Sometimes a file could have a mix of encodings.

Somewhere I found this brute-force handy little script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Usage string-encoding-detector.sh fileWithLiberaci°n.txt | grep Liberación

iconv --list | sed -e 's/\/\///g' | while read -r encoding
do
  transcoded=$(head -n1 "$1" | iconv -c -f "$encoding" -t UTF-8)
  echo "$encoding $transcoded"
done
```

### To convert

- [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) (recommended)
- [recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html)

### Related

- [Plain Text - Dylan Beattie - NDC Oslo 2021 - YouTube](https://youtu.be/_mZBa3sqTrI)
- Multiple files at once: [How to change encoding from Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators to UTF-8?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306404/209677)
- [Check files for conventions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172358/209677)

Comment: recode uses iconv under the hood, btw.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, no it doesn't.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well, it isn't *solely* based on it, but the README clearly states: "It recognises or produces over 200 different character sets (or about 300 if combined with an iconv library) and transliterates files between almost any pair." ... but it doesn't seem to *rely* on it. My bad.